# convert int into String in servlet Java

Tags: java, servlets

```
myModule.setNumber(request.getParameter("txtNo"));
```

This code is inside my servlet, and i want to change the type from Int to String .

Thanks .

Comment: If only Java provided a method to parse an int...  (Tongue slightly away from cheek:  look for parse and int and Java, and you'll find what you're looking for.)

Comment: This appears to be off-topic because the OP put forth 0 effort...

Comment: @Takendarkk:  That alone doesn't make it off-topic.  But, it's certainly not a good quality question.

Comment: Hey hey hey, I said _appears..._ :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get value in a string and parse value using [ParseInt](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt(java.lang.String)) function.

```
//variable s was not defined
String s = request.getParameter("txtNo");
int number= Integer.parseInt(s);
```

Answer (score 0):

Int to String:
String randomString = String.valueOf(integer);

String to Int:

int randomInt = Integer.valueOf(string);

Answer (score 0):

You can convert `String` to `int` with [`Integer.parseInt(String)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt%28java.lang.String%29), and you can convert `int` to `String` with [`String.valueOf(int)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#valueOf%28int%29).

```
String str = String.valueOf(10);
int i = Integer.parseInt(str);
System.out.printf("%s = %d%n", str, i);
```